# Not able to start "bin/cassandra -f" from CYGWIN Terminal

Tags: linux, windows, cassandra, cygwin

I am new to windows 8 . Prior I was using Mac Yosemite . Now I have installed cygwin to run linux commands . If I try to start cassandra by untar - ing the installation , I am getting error .

```
pargavi@laptop /cygdrive/d/MyWork/Software/apache-cassandra-2.1.9
$ bin/cassandra -f
bin/cassandra: line 101: [: C:\Program: binary operator expected
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Program...
```

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 0):

It's because "Program Files" have a space. The best solution would be to use for cygwin and cassandra directory without spaces in the path.

I recommend you to install everything that work with cygwin (and cygwin itself) in places without empty spaces (avoid "C:\Program Files\")

Comment: Reinstalling entire is like not fixing issues . Still thanks a lot

Comment: The same "C:\Program: " ? Did you install it again in to the folder with spaces ?

Answer (score 0):

After some workaround I found Git Shell which is shell tool for windows. It started direct uploading and installing from windows .

Actually the path in Windows Machine is C:/Program Files/.. and  (/ or \) path separators in linux or java vocabulary. They ( spaces and slashes ) are giving lot of trouble who are pitching in to windows environment either from MAC or Linux background .

But look and feel of CGYWIN is awesome and gives the real feel of working in Terminals of MAC and linux. But shell scripts having path variable giving head ache for new comers of Windows .

Looking from cassandra point of view , people has started learning from Datastax where demos are shown in linux terminals.So this is the reason why I have been doing workaround on it .

Please start "Git Shell"

```
C:\Users\pargavi\Documents\GitHub> cd D:
D:\> cd .\MyWork\Software\apache-cassandra-2.1.9
D:\MyWork\Software\apache-cassandra-2.1.9> .\bin\cassandra -f
Setting up Cassandra environment
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
*---------------------------------------------------------------------*
Starting cassandra server
INFO  09:37:43 Hostname: -Ur Hostname-
INFO  09:37:43 Loading settings from file:/C:/Program%20Files/DataStax%20Community/apache-cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml...
```

Finally I am surpized and happy enough !!! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because of less RAM size in your system
Do the following :
 1. edit Cassandra batch file.`(<cassandra_location>/bin/cassandra.bat)`
 2. find  `-Xms2G^   and    -Xmx2G^`
 3. Edit it by specifying `less heap space`
 eg: `-Xms512M^ and -Xmx512M^` respectively